# Manually determine the type of an expression

Tags: haskell, types

How would I go about determining the type of an expression by hand, instead of using `:type` in GHCi?

For basic expressions we can do it by just looking at the expression and come up with some type.

Is there some kind of algorithmic approach for more complex expressions like `(.) . (.)`?

Comment: As far as I know, you can use the [*Hindley-Milner type system (algorithm W)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system)

Answer (score 5):

Knowing Hindle-Milner is definitely a possibility, but in many cases, you can get to a correct result using just a little bit of intuition.

As you say, for basic expressions it's quite easy. Let's say you've got a simple function like `f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. When you apply this function to an `Integer` (ie. something like `f 42`), you can immediately see that the type of this is `Integer -> Integer`. Trivial.

The fun begins once you start introducing type variables and constraints. Even though the basic concepts are still the same - applying a function of type `a -> b` to an expression of type `a` yields you a `b` - you have to be careful to not mix up all the type variables and to not forget the constraints.

Let's take your example of `(.) . (.)` and go through it, step by step.

- First of all, let's rewrite it as `((.) (.)) (.)` - this an application of `(.)` to `(.)` with the result being applied to yet another `(.)`. Let's just focus on the first application and take care of the second one later.
- As you know, the type of `(.)` is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` and in this case we're applying it to itself - therefore, we have to unify the type of the first argument (ie. `b -> c`) with the type of `(.)`. This is the part where you have to be careful about your type variables - for this reason, I'll rename the type variables of the second (and later even the third) `(.)` to `(b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1` - this has no effect on the actual type, it just makes it easy for us to not get lost later.
- With this renaming now in place, let's unify the type of `b -> c` with the type `(b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1`. `b` gets unified with `b1 -> c1` and `c` gets unified with the rest, `(a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1`. As there are no constraints on any of the type variables, we don't need to care about those.
- Now that we know the actual types that `b` and `c` represent, we can substitute these into the type of `(.)` (ignoring the first parameter, because we've just applied that) and we'll end up with this: `(a -> b1 -> c1) -> a -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1`
- Now we can move on by applying this to the last remaining `(.)`.
- We need to unify the type of the last `(.)` (whose type variables I'll rename to `a2`, `b2` and `c2`, so it becomes `(b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2`) with `(a -> b1 -> c1)`. This is, again, easy. `a` becomes `b2 -> c2`, `b1` becomes `a2 -> b2` and finally `c1` becomes `a2 -> c2`.
- Once again, we can substitute these into our original type before the unification, ignoring the parameter that represents the `(.)` we've just applied, We'll get `(b2 -> c2) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b2) -> a1 -> a2 -> c2` and we are done.

Ignoring different names, you can see that this is exactly the same result you'd get by using `:t (.) . (.)`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fun fact: "Ignoring different names" is a plain English translation of the mathematical concept of [*alpha equivalence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat graphical view of type inference.
We want to find the type of

```
(.)  .  (.) :: ?
```

For that we first list out the type of each variable, using fresh type variables. Putting lots of parentheses will also help avoid mistakes in the next steps.

```
    (.)     :: (a1 -> a2) -> ((a0 -> a1) -> (a0 -> a2))
(.)         :: (b1 -> b2) -> ((b0 -> b1) -> (b0 -> b2))
        (.) :: (c1 -> c2) -> ((c0 -> c1) -> (c0 -> c2))
```

Then we align the types so the types of arguments match with the type of functions. First, for a simpler example, if we wanted to find the type of `f x y` where

```
f     :: a -> a -> a
  x   :: b
    y :: c
```

then we would align the types as follows

```
f     :: a -> (a -> a)
  x   :: b             -- First argument
    y ::       c        -- Second argument
                 -- ^ Result type
```

Because `x` is the first argument of `f`, and `y` the second. This tells us to equate `a = b` and `a = c`, and that the result type is `a`

Here's what the diagram looks like for the original problem, adding lots of whitespace to stretch expressions so they match.

```
    (.)     :: (a1         -> a2                        ) -> (a0         -> a1                        ) -> (a0 -> a2)
(.)         ::  (b1 -> b2) -> ((b0 -> b1) -> (b0 -> b2))
        (.) ::                                                (c1 -> c2) -> ((c0 -> c1) -> (c0 -> c2))
                                                                                                        -- ^ Result
```

By looking at the columns these form, we obtain the following equations between types:

```
a1 = (b1 -> b2)
a2 = ((b0 -> b1) -> (b0 -> b2))
a0 = (c1 -> c2)
a1 = ((c0 -> c1) -> (c0 -> c2))
```

From the first one and the last one, we deduce further two more equations

```
b1 = (c0 -> c1)
b2 = (c0 -> c2)
```

And the result type is `(a0 -> a2)`, i.e., after substitution:

```
(c1 -> c2) -> (b0 -> c0 -> c1) -> (b0 -> c0 -> c2)
```